# Adjust Mysql timezone at Bluehost

Tags: mysql, bluehost

I am trying to adjust the timezone of mysql at bluehost but when I try to execute SET GLOBAL time_zone = "+05:30"; I get an error "#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"

Does anyone here use bluehost and can please help me finding a way to adjust the timezone? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to set the global timezone that would set the time zone for the entire server and every user using it. That's clearly not acceptable on a shared server.

You can set the timezone for your session with

```
set time_zone = <timezone>;
```

E.g

```
set time_zone = 'UTC';

set time_zone = 'Pacific/Auckland';

set time_zone = '+10:00';
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: The problem is that I have a website with datatable connected to a mysql that is hosted by bluehost. I upload the data to bluehost mysql and the time and date keep changing. In my computer I can see the correct time and date but on my website the time and date uses the server time and date. Not sure if it is allowed but have a look, this is what is happening: http://ozgamefinder.com/index.php

Comment: The time and date in the table should be 7:45 PM that is the hour in Australia now.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the time zone for your PHP scripts too - [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). Timezones are a nightmare. Australia has three, and daylight-saving in some states and not others. When I've done this I've used UTC everywhere on the server and relied on some client-side code to translate to the user's time zone.

Comment: Shall I add this code to my index.php file? Or put this somewhere in the server?

Comment: You can add `date_default_timezone_set()` to `index.php`, which will deal with any time handling the server does now. You should also set the MySQL session time to match as part of the code that sets up the connection. That won't help with existing data which you'll have to update somehow.